# WIF: How to specify which claims to return upon authentication?

Tags: c#, wif, claims-based-identity

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638471/how-do-i-request-additional-claims-from-passive-sts-with-wif), except I need to get additional claims at the moment of authentication, not later.

I'm implementing my RP as an authentication plugin to another website, so I can't (or rather would like to avoid if at all possible) do such things as alter the `web.config` file or add `FederationMetadata.xml` to my RP.

I've managed to sucessfully authenticate against the STS, now I need to get some more claims besides the very basics that it sends me. The STS is public (or near it), out of my control, and there will be many different RP's authenticating against it, so I don't expect that every RP will receive special treatment. I thus assume that the STS doesn't know anything about my RP until I perform an authentication, and that it will forget all about it after the authentication is complete.

As stated, I'm using WIF and I'm doing everything in code. Where do I specify which claims to send? Here's my code so far:

```
// Init configuration
var config = new ServiceConfiguration();
config.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri("https://MyAudienceURI/"));
config.CertificateValidator = System.IdentityModel.Selectors.X509CertificateValidator.None;
var issuers = new ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry();
issuers.AddTrustedIssuer("08F81147C44D95CDA617963AFF0650EF26578E4A", "http://STSIssuer/trust");
config.IssuerNameRegistry = issuers;

// Create the FAM
var fam = new WSFederationAuthenticationModule();
fam.ServiceConfiguration = config;
fam.PassiveRedirectEnabled = true;
fam.Issuer = "https://STSUrl/Default.aspx";
fam.Realm = "https://MyAudienceURI/";
fam.Reply = Request.Url.ToString();
fam.RequireHttps = false;

// Check the current request
var req = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
if (!fam.CanReadSignInResponse(req, true))
{
    fam.RedirectToIdentityProvider("Nop.Plugin.ExternalAuth.WIF", Request.Url.ToString(), false);
    Response.End();
}

var principal = ClaimsPrincipal.CreateFromIdentities(config.SecurityTokenHandlers.ValidateToken(fam.GetSecurityToken(fam.GetSignInResponseMessage(req))));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, the STS is configured to provide the claims. The configuration is on a per RP basis so different RP can get different claims.

You can augment this using WIF.

Use the ClaimsAuthenticationManager and override Authenticate.

and then something like:

((IClaimsIdentity)incomingPrincipal.Identity).Claims.Add(new Claim(...))

If the claims are external, you have to get them yourself e.g. accessing AD?

Comment: Yeah, I figured out as much. But turns out there's also a parameter - `fam.Request` and `fam.RequestPtr` that can be used to pass a request for specific claims. I used that, and it worked. I'll accept your answer though, since it's the only one. :)